# Error in Sckit learn code: " digits: Bunch Instance of 'tuple' has no 'target' memberpylint(no-member) " .How to fix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

VScode shows error under the "digits" in print function**

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np

iris = datasets.load_iris()
digits = datasets.load_digits()
print(digits.target)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using syntax for an older version of sklearn. Try the following.

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np

iris = datasets.load_iris()
data, target = datasets.load_digits()
print(target)
```